# How to disable recaptcha?

Tags: php, recaptcha

Obsolite, Old question was like:

Is there a way to turn off the recaptcha, created using noscript? I used the standard example, but now I have to make it disappear for certain IPs. I know how to get the ip, but I have not figured out how to turn recaptcha off. I have a wild idea to use php(html) to spawn recaptca, so it can be "turned off" easily.

What it should have been:

I am trying to turn off recaptcha, created using noscript, standard example was taken.

Right now the general outline of the code is below, some parts are obviously missing

```
<?php
.......
require_once('IpChecker.php');

$in_range = check_ip($ip);

if(!$in_range)
{
   if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]){......}
.......
?>
.............

<?php
   if(!$in_range)
   {
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
   }
?>
```

It does work correctly but I get an annoing php notice, which basically tells that `recaptcha_response_field` required in the top part, only appears in the bottom part inside `recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error)`. I am mainly trying to get rid of annoing php notice.

UPDATE: I am a moron. Period. There should be a check if the request was a `POST` at all - `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')` and then there should probably be a check `if (isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]))`

Given my experience I now see that `if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"])` is not really correct way to do things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$some_ips = array("127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.33");
if(! in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $some_ips)){

    Your recaptcha stuff here...

}
```